# how to set python path for ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I have somehow messed up the anaconda installation. So now I am working with default python at `/usr/bin/python`. All imports etc working fine here. But my ipython (that came with anaconda) still uses `~/anaconda2/bin/python` and as such I can't import a few modules that I installed for `usr/bin/python`. How can I set the default python path for ipython? I have tried using `alias` command but that doesn't seem to work. `pip install ipython` says `Requirement already satisfied`

Comment: You probably should clean up the mess instead of trying to work around your actual problems. Anaconda installations can be easily cleaned up by removing `~/anaconda2/` and installing a fresh version from the website.

Comment: hmm. you nudged me into action :) but just out of curiosity how could you change the python path for ipython ;)

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, I've never tried to make it work. For the notebook I would not fiddle with PYTHONPATH, but install a kernel instead.